# AutoSize not fitting my custom UI control

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

i am a begginer at ui design and windows forms in general. And i am encountering some issues when designing a custom control control

The issue that i am having is that windows forms is not fitting my control properly

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Even by disabling AutoSize, it still looks wrong.

Again, i am not very experienced, and i watched a tutorial to make this switch button.

As you can see, the edges of the circle are completly cut, and i dont know why

Here is the code:

```cs
public AzTogglebutton()
        {
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(50, 22);
        }

        private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath()
        {
            int arcSize = this.Height - 1;
            Rectangle leftArc = new Rectangle(0, 0, arcSize, arcSize);
            Rectangle rightArc = new Rectangle(this.Width - arcSize - 2, 0, arcSize, arcSize);
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            path.StartFigure();
            path.AddArc(leftArc, 90, 180);
            path.AddArc(rightArc, 270, 180);
            path.CloseFigure();
            return path;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            int toggleSize = this.Height + 3;
            pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            pevent.Graphics.Clear(this.Parent.BackColor);
            if (this.Checked) //ON
            {
                //Draw the control surface
                if (solidStyle)
                    pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(onBackColor), GetFigurePath());
                else pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(onBackColor, 2), GetFigurePath());
                //Draw the toggle
                pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(onToggleColor),
                  new Rectangle(this.Width - this.Height + - 2, -2, toggleSize, toggleSize));
            }
            else //OFF
            {
                //Draw the control surface
                if (solidStyle)
                    pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(offBackColor), GetFigurePath());
                else pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(offBackColor, 2), GetFigurePath());
                //Draw the toggle
                pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(offToggleColor),
                  new Rectangle(-2, -2, toggleSize, toggleSize));
            }
        }
```

Comment: We don't know what's wrong with the image.

Comment: As you can see, its not a full circle, the edges are completly cut, and i dont know why, sorry for not elaborating

Comment: Did you make this image in a paint program?  Or did you draw it in code?  Paste the relevant code into your question.

Comment: I followed a youtube tutorial, i will edit with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some adjustments to the size you are using:

```
private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath()
{
  var arcSize = this.ClientSize.Height;
  var leftArc = new Rectangle(0, 0, arcSize, arcSize - 1);
  var rightArc = new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - arcSize - 1, 0, arcSize, arcSize - 1);
  var path = new GraphicsPath();
  path.StartFigure();
  path.AddArc(leftArc, 90, 180);
  path.AddArc(rightArc, 270, 180);
  path.CloseFigure();
  return path;
}
```

For consistency, I would continue to use a GraphicsPath to draw the highlight circle:

```
private GraphicsPath GetOnPath()
{
  var arcSize = this.ClientSize.Height;
  var leftArc = new Rectangle(0, 0, arcSize, arcSize - 1);
  var rightArc = new Rectangle(0, 0, arcSize, arcSize - 1);
  var path = new GraphicsPath();
  path.StartFigure();
  path.AddArc(leftArc, 90, 180);
  path.AddArc(rightArc, 270, 180);
  path.CloseFigure();
  return path;
}
```

The end result:

```
pevent.Graphics.Clear(this.Parent.BackColor);
pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
          
pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(offBackColor), GetFigurePath());
pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(offToggleColor), GetOnPath());
```

[image]

Comment: `pevent.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half` for a perfect fill. Note the edges.